# there is not any errors in validationResult

Tags: node.js, express-validator

I used express-validator (6.2.0) in my nodejs project:
I have a form element like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="/register" novalidate>
    <input type="email" name="email" >
  </form>
```

and register route is:

```
   router.post('/register',registerController.registerProcess);
```

and finally, registerController:

```
 const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
     registerProcess(req, res, next) {

      check('email', 'Email Error ').isEmail();

      const errors = validationResult(req);
            if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
               res.json({ errors: errors.array()  });
             } else {
               res.json(req.body);
             }

     }
```

validationResult(req) always is empty: what is my problem?

could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it.
in  previous versions there is request.checkBody() function but it has not been used in this new version.

we have to use from

```
post('/action-route' , check() , check(), check() , (req,res) =>{
const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            res.json({ errors: errors.array()  });
        } else {
            res.json(req.body);
        }
});
```

actually . in my idea it is a ridiculous way.